# Arbitrary in-place transformation of arbitrary nested POJOs based on a rule set

Tags: java

I tried searching any existing implementations/library for this but did not find any. Is there any library which would do this? Is there a name for this kind of patter (e.g. something like JavaBean visitor maybe? but normally the entries to be visited have a visit method or similar)

Constraints:

- C1: POJO Object (only get/setters, default constructor), can be of multiple types (10s of types)
- C2: POJO's source cannot be changed
- C3: POJO has nested other POJOs (which have nested POJOs and so on)
- C4: A common rule set for all types

I would input one object to the system and receive it back transformed (the "in-place" requirement is not that critical) based on some rules (preferable a hierarchical rule system).

Example rules:

- R1: Transform each String by adding something to the end of them
- R2: Transform each String if the are equal to "test" to "test2"
- R3: Add 1 to each Integer

The rules should be applied to each nested structure so lets say we have

```
a.getB().getC().getD().getE().getString()
```

R1 should apply (unless R2 has "more priority", then it should apply instead). The new value would be set using

```
a.getB().getC().getD().getE().setString(transformedString)
```

Also if any getter returns an array, it should be traversed and rules applied to each element (unless there is a rule to replace the whole array, e.g. "set all arrays to null" -rule).

Why?  I have around 50 different POJOs that have 1~5 layers of nesting of other POJOs that I need to transform a bit". The transformation logic is more or less common for all the types, e.g. for instance of type X replace it with new X based on transformation Y (which might or might not depend on the value of the instance). Where the instances of X are (i.e. "path" a.getb.getc etc.) in a particular POJO depends on the POJO.

I most likely end up coding my own solution, but just wanted to ask if there are known implementations out there?